# Interrupts do not fire

Tags: stm32, stm32f4

Question will be deleted shortly. Made a stupid mistake,these IRQs are supposed to be triggered by buttons. I meant to ask why don't they fire on their own automatically.

Interrupt handlers are not triggered. That's a book code
for the most part. Board based on : stm32f411RE Nucleo.

The code is meant for f429 but form my research it looks like it should be
fine.

Edit:
Adding this line makes it fire, but only once:

```
EXTI->SWIER = EXTI_SWIER_SWIER0|EXTI_SWIER_SWIER2;
```

So I need to reset a flag for this somehow. 
But why the original hardware interrupts do not trigger.

```
int main(void) 
{     
RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOAEN | RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOBEN;
RCC->APB2ENR = RCC_APB2ENR_SYSCFGEN; 
__DSB();

GPIOA->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE5_0; 
GPIOB->PUPDR |= GPIO_PUPDR_PUPD2_0;

    SYSCFG->EXTICR[0] = SYSCFG_EXTICR1_EXTI0_PB | SYSCFG_EXTICR1_EXTI2_PB ;

    EXTI->FTSR = EXTI_FTSR_TR2;    
    EXTI->RTSR = EXTI_RTSR_TR0;
    EXTI->IMR = EXTI_IMR_MR0 | EXTI_IMR_MR2;

    NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI0_IRQn);
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI2_IRQn);

    while (1);
    } 
/* main */
void EXTI0_IRQHandler(void) 
{
        if ( EXTI->PR & EXTI_PR_PR0) 
        {
            EXTI->PR = EXTI_PR_PR0;

            GPIOA->ODR ^= GPIO_ODR_OD5;    }

}

void EXTI2_IRQHandler(void) 
{
        if ( EXTI->PR & EXTI_PR_PR2) 
        {
            EXTI->PR = EXTI_PR_PR2;
            GPIOA->ODR ^= GPIO_ODR_OD5;   
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You also have to clear the pending IRQ in the NVIC, something like

NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(EXTI0_IRQn);

In addition, you need to make sure the interrupt vector table have the correct entries for your handlers. Usually the interrupt vector table is in the startup file, but it depends on your system.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Using this and NVIC_SetPendingIRQ() got me the required result but the question is why the register way from the book doesn't work, that bugs me. Need some time to figure out what you've said about the vector table. No rep, cant vote;)

Comment: What do you mean by "the register way from the book doesn't work"? The NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ (not ...*Set*...) is a separate requirement from the code you showed. It's just something you need to do with the ARM Cortex-M MCU. If your book's code elide that, I'd think it's a mistake on the book's part. I have no idea why someone downvoted my answer ;-)

Comment: From what i understand setting this register should be enough- EXTI->IMR = EXTI_IMR_MR0 | EXTI_IMR_MR2; Edit: enough to fire the IRQ's

Comment: sooooory. IRQs were supposed to be triggered by buttons;))) Confirm you got it and I delete the question;)

Comment: Or should I leave it?

Comment: I thought they should fire on their own automatically, as in previous example with timers. ;)

Comment: I would leave the question up, even if it is incorrect. You never know when someone else makes the same mistake...